# Ionic | Avoid content hidden under keyboard

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im using Ionic with Angular to build an app.

Problem: When focus changes from one text-input to another text-input, bottom content is pushed underneath the keyboard (please see below GIF. When focus changes from left-most input to right-most input, the "next" button disappears.)

**Question:** How can I fix this annoying bug?

[image]

Please consider the following code:

```
<ion-content fullscreen="true">
  <div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <h1 class="welcome-header">Whats your full name?</h1>
    <div fxFlex="0 0 20px"></div>
    <ng-container [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="name-container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="12px">
        <div class="input-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
          <ion-item fxFlex>
            <ion-input placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName"
                       (focusout)="$event.preventDefault()"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item fxFlex>
            <ion-input placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
        <span class="name-text">
        People use real names on xyz :) Thnx!
      </span>
      </div>

    </ng-container>

    <div fxFlex></div>
    <ion-button expand="full" shape="round" color="secondary" (mousedown)="$event.preventDefault();"
                (click)="submit()">
      <ng-container *ngIf="!loading">
        Next ->
      </ng-container>
      <ion-spinner *ngIf="loading"></ion-spinner>
    </ion-button>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: add Next  in ion-footer

Comment: @RaviAshara that does unfortunately not work

Comment: can you share ts code??